# What happens to the complementary base when the other undergoes a base substitution mutation?

Tags: genetics, dna, gene-expression

From what I know only the base pairs A and T/U, or G and C can occur due to hydrogen bonding. So if a base substitution mutation occurs, say an A is replaced by a C on the strand, does it affect only one of the strands on the DNA or does it changes the base pair entirely? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a stretch of DNA

```
A T C C T C
T A G G A G
```

Let's say that during replication a nucleotide get switched

```
A G C C T C
T A G G A G
```

Now, this does not work. The cellular machinery will find this location and try to solve it. It will either resolve it as

```
A T C C T C
T A G G A G
```

and no mutation would have happened. Or it will solve it as

```
A G C C T C
T C G G A G
```

and a mutation just happened.

You might want to read about [DNA repair mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_repair).

Answer (score 0):

A base substitution mutation often occur during replication of DNA. Remember that the template strand is methylated, in order to understand *who* will be the new synthetized strand between both.

Having this scenario, with a nucleotide substitution mutation in the 3rd position from 5' , the 5'-3' strand is the fresh synthetized.

The DNA polymerase will trait just the 5'-3' strand as *something to work on* : if a mutation happens the proof-reading activity of the DNA polymerase will try to cut off the wrong base, and to re-synthetize this piece of the strand.

```
5'- A G G T T C G -3' --> new strand
3'- T C A A A G C -5' --> template
```

If it isn't able to figure the mutation, it'll be fixed in the next replication process, so the mutation will be fixed into the considered DNA.